# MySQL View Error - No database selected

Tags: mysql, view, odbc, toad

I'm defined the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW db_a1.qry_result AS
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM db_a1.tbl_result
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db_a1.tbl_result_archive) a;
```

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM db_a1.qry_result 
WHERE customer = 2;
```

then the view run through without any error and the results are correct.
However, If a select the view object (via TOAD for MySQL) or try to connect via ODBC (ODBC Connector 5.3.8 for 32 and 64bit) I retrive the error "No Database selected". Selection via ODBC are not possible.

Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help in advance
Best regards

Andreas

Comment: you may try to solve it by creating a separate connection for each database in the same server, and set it as the default database of that connection.

Comment: That is a one view in one database schema, e.g. one connection to the view. The view contains two table selects in one database schema. Even if I define it clear:

CREATE VIEW qry_result AS
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM tbl_result
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl_result_archive) a;

I receive the same error. If I want to open the view, error occure.